# How to format to NTFS my EXT4 partition on Windows 8?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, partitioning, ntfs, ext4

I'd like to format one of my partitions to NTFS which is EXT4 at the moment and an ubuntu is installed on, that I don't need anymore.

I can't see the partition in My Computer and I've never tried anything like that so I don't know what to do.

How can I erase it and create NTFS on that?

Comment: Just delete the partition using the tool of your choice then create the partition from within Windows.

Comment: Like what tool and where?

Comment: The disk management tool of your choice.  I would just use the one already built into Windows.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can make us of the Windows Disk Management Utility to re-format the partition as NTFS. Just launch `Computer Management` (`Control Panel->System and Security->Administrative Tools->Computer Management` and choose "`Disk Management`" from left pane).

Now, on the right pane, right-click on the partition you want tp re-format and choose `Format`, then choose "NTFS" from the drop down and format it.

Answer (score 3):

Go to command line (start run (or windows key + r) cmd enter)
From command line run:

```
diskpart
list disk
```

Find the hard disk that has your partition and type:

```
select disk <disk number>
list partition
```

Find the partition you want to format

```
select partition <partition number>
delete partition
create partition primary
format fs=ntfs
```

Answer (score 0):

I found something that works for me.

Select your partition in diskpart, then do `delete partition override`.